# Reading values from .data and .rdata of exe. Bytes alignment

Tags: c++, layout, binary, exe, ifstream

I have one very small exe that I compile from this code (debug, no optimalization):

```
struct some_data
{
    unsigned long long a;
    unsigned long long b;
}

int main ()
{
    constexpr some_data {0x1234567890abcdef, 0xabcdabcdabcdabcd}
    cout << some_data.a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now i want to make another program that would find value 0x1234567890abcdef in the first exe and replace it with 0x111111111111111 then save the exe, so next time I run it I get the "injected" 0x111111111111111  as output.

I made a simple program that would do something along these lines:

```
uint64_t key = 0x1234567890abcdef;
uint64_t value;
fstream file ("file", ios::in| ios::out | ios::binary);
if (file.is_open())
{
while (not_end_of_file) {
    file.read (&value, sizeof(value));
    if (value == key) {
        //code that overwrittes the old value with new
    }
}
```

It did work once or twice which made me happy, but after I added some code to the first project and rebuilt it, the replacing (2nd project) suddenly stopped working. In stopped entering the if (value == key)part of code. The reason why i think this happend is that after adding some code, the struct in .data section moved a few bytes forward in the file, and now when reading chunks of 8 bytes its no longer in one chunk like this (little_endianess)

```
XX XX XX ef cd ab 90 78        one read    operation   
56 34 12 XX XX XX XX XX        the next read operation
```

Do you think this is the case? Can I expect the .data and .rdata section to be alligned in any dependable way? How would you implement the checking that would take such shift into consideration? Or maybe someone has totally different idea how to easily programmatically change this value.

Best regards
Marcin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you cant depend on a data allignment or at least not the way I did before.

**NOTE** If you wanna copy the implementation you better use **code from dereferencer's answer** as its simply clearer. I leave my answer for the information regarding data allignment and an alternative way to implement it.

This is the code I came up with that loads bytes 1 by 1 and checks the last 8 bytes. It's for little endianess, for big I believe you would need to change with byte is "value" referencing, and change the shift direction.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

using magic_bytes_t = uint64_t;
const magic_bytes_t search_key{ 0x1234567890abcdef };
const magic_bytes_t replacemenet_key{ 0x1212121212121212 };

struct data_struct
{
    const magic_bytes_t value_to_replace;
};

union parsing_union
{
    magic_bytes_t value;
    uint8_t bytes[sizeof(magic_bytes_t)];
};

int main()
{
    std::fstream myFile("C:\\Users\\crazy_path\\x64\\Debug\\SampleApplication.exe", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    if (!myFile) {
        cout << "Couldn't open file" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else {

        parsing_union parsing_helper{ 0x0000000000000000 };
        uint8_t &single_byte_value = parsing_helper.bytes[7];

        while (myFile.read((char*)&single_byte_value, sizeof(single_byte_value)))
        {
            if (parsing_helper.value == search_key)
            {
                uint64_t control_key_start_position = myFile.tellg();
                control_key_start_position -= sizeof(parsing_helper.value);

                myFile.seekp(control_key_start_position);
                myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&replacemenet_key), sizeof(replacemenet_key));
                cout << "GOT EM !! GOT EM GOOD" << endl;;
                break;
            } else {
                parsing_helper.value >>= (sizeof(single_byte_value) * 8);
            }
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might look a bit ghetto, but you could load the entire file into a byte array and dereference the bytes to an uint64_t like so:

(yeah sorry i didn't include a full code, but this should give you an idea/be clear)

```
byte* bytes = new byte[filesizeinbytes];
//read to the byte array
then:
DWORD offset = 0;
while( *(uint64_t*)((DWORD)bytes+offset) != 0x1234567890abcdef )
{
    offset++;
}
//We found the right address, so we can replace the bytes/address/offset
*(uint64_t*)((DWORD)bytes+offset) = 0x111111111111111;

//write the entire file, starting from bytes till the end of the file

delete[] bytes; // free the allocated memory
bytes = 0;
```